# InvalidOperationException: A named connection string was used, but the name was not found

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, ef-core-3.1

I have two project one .net core web api and another class library where i have  dbContext file. And i have created one separate class in class library to get data from database. But it's showing above error.

Comment: Can you share the code of your DbContext and the code ConfigureServices method within your WebAPI startup.cs?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the connection configuration to the main Web API project. Simply copy the relevant section from your class library config to your web api one.

The reason is simple, the solution will build, your class library becomes a dll and that dll is copied over to the web api's bin folder and is loaded from there.

The web api does not have the connection details in its configuration so you get this issue.